# PHP-Diff skip script Tags

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am currently using https://github.com/rashid2538/php-htmldiff for diffing two html pages but the problem is that content within `<script></script>` tags is also diffed which I don't want to, since it ruins the runnability. I have looked at the code but I can not figure out where to adjust in order to ignore script tags since I am only getting started with php as my first language. I understand the parsing principle of the code but everything else is quite cryptic to me.

Can someone please advise or give hints on what to change?

file1:

```
<html>
    <head>
       <script> var thing = 'test'; </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

file2:

```
<html>
    <head>
       <script> var thing = 'anothertest'; </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Result:

```
<html>
    <head>
       <script> var thing = '<del class="diffmod">test</del><ins class="diffmod">anothertest</ins>'; </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Include examples of the HTML files that you are diff'ing.

Comment: Show your code otherwise it is to broad what you are asking.

Comment: @JuanDiego I included the basic example. The code for the HTML-Diff just send two strings into https://github.com/rashid2538/php-htmldiff/blob/master/HtmlDiff.php

Answer (score 0):

You could use `regex` to find the script tags from the two `html` strings and then delete them with [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php). After that, use the two strings with the `htmldiff` function

```
$regex = '/<script\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/script>/i';
$html1_parsed = preg_replace($regex, '', $html1);
$html2_parsed = preg_replace($regex, '', $html2);
```

Comment: I thought about that but that would mean that the diff page does not have any javascript at all which unfortunately can not be an option. I guess I could try searching for script tags and reinsert them after the diff.